# How do I hide meeting attendees in Outlook 2010?

Tags: microsoft-outlook, microsoft-office, microsoft-outlook-2010, exchange, exchange-2010

### Background

I am an IT Service Manager of sorts in my current position. We use Outlook 2010 and Exchange at the company.

For server outages, etc... I prefer to send calendar events so it can help users coordinate, send an alert before the event happens, and more.

However, when I invite a list of people, the list is expanded to include all the recipients. This is not an issue by itself, but when it is a whole building full of people, I would prefer that the invitees are not able to see and message each other.

### Question

How do I, using MS Outlook 2010 / Exchange, prevent meeting attendees from seeing other attendants or doing a "reply all"?

Is this possible?

Answer (score 2):

I would think that the best way to achieve this is to create a LIST (distribution list).

I don't believe that the list is expanded but instead appears as a single name.

The Distribution List can unfortunately still be expanded by recipients.

Comment: A distribution list would hide the names by default, but it can still be expanded to show all recipients.  Not sure if there is a way to disable that feature.  I don't think it would stop you from doing a "reply all" either.

Comment: I didn't think that a server created list did expand, I thought that was one of its features - perhaps I getting mixed up with a real mail server! I think that you could easily put a filter in place to prevent people from sending to the list.

Answer (score 2):

You can bcc. You have to add users as Resources. This works with Outlook 2013 also.

Answer (score 1):

If you could BCC the meeting invites it would work great, but Outlook doesn't support that.  There is a roundabout way to do it, however.

Create a meeting on your calendar with all the necessary details, but don't add any attendees to it.  When you click the Send button, Outlook will warn you there are no attendees and will ask if you just want to save it to your calendar.  Once you do this, create a new email and drag the calendar item to it as an attachment.

Sending it as an attachment will allow you to use the BCC field of the email (so no one can see each other in the address list) but they will be able to open and accept the meeting invitation (click the `Copy to my calendar` button).  It will send the normal "accepted" emails back to you as organizer, but in the meeting details each person should see only you and him or herself.  One potential downside is that I'm not sure you can cancel the meeting and have it remove from everyone's calendar automatically.  Maybe it will, I haven't tried it.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a listserv available, you could create a list that includes everyone but only you have send permissions.  I don't believe there is any built-in way with Outlook and Exchange to do what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

i have been using the resource field, and it does work as a BCC. major downside: i am not receiving accept/decline responses from attendees.

Answer (score 0):

You can disable ReplyAll on a custom meeting form.

Open meeting as ususal.

Under the Developer tab click on Design This Form

On the Actions tab double-click on Reply To All

On the Form Action Properties box uncheck "Enabled" OK

Publish Form

Choose a location in the "Look In".

Give it a descriptive name.

---

You can either got through "Choose a form" to generate this form or set it up as the default.

Right click on the calendar in the navigation pane.

On the General tab change "When posting to this folder, use"

You should see the name of your new meeting form in the ribbon replacing the original button.